# android Clear Button in a simple counter

Tags: java, android, debugging, button, counter

I have a counter program for number. I define 3 buttons for Plus, Minus and Clear.
When I use clear button for clear TextView it's good. But after using Plus and Minus it it is Continuation last counter. that is my code.
please Help me.

```
public class CounterActivity extends Activity {

private Button   btnPlus;
private Button   btnMinus;
private Button   btnClear;
private TextView txtCounter;

int              counter = 0;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.counter_menu);

    btnPlus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlus);
    btnMinus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMinus);
    btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
    txtCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCounter);

    btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            counter++;
            txtCounter.setText(counter + "");
        }
    });

    btnMinus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            counter--;
            txtCounter.setText(counter + "");
        }
    });

    btnClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txtCounter.setText(0 + "");
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: You should reset your ```counter``` variable as well....

Comment: Assign counter = 0 when you clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your clear button `onClick` method as follows:

```
btnClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        counter = 0;
        txtCounter.setText(0 + "");
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I searched for one day, but i didn't found answer.thansk. now it work